# Azure Secrets stored in aws secret manager

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I am working with terraform to spin up different resource in azure. Some of those resources have sensitive data that I would like to store securely in aws secret manager.
Is this a doable process in terraform?
What it is confusing me is the following question:

To be able to access aws secret manager and spin up azure resources, should I have both provider declared in my terraform?

thank you very much for any advice and clarification you can offer

Comment: Azure has an equivalent secrets manager service that you can use.

Comment: do you mean azure key vault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To be able to access aws secret manager and spin up azure resources,
> should I have both provider declared in my terraform?

Of course, yes. You need to configure Azure provider and AWS provider for each one.

And I agree with Matt, if the resources have sensitive data, you can use the Azure Key Vault. then you can use only one provider and it will spend less time to get them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In term of security, azure key vault and aws secret manager are the same?

Comment: @NaydenVan I have no experience with AWS secret. But I think the Azure key vault is secure as the AWS secret.

Comment: @NaydenVan Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?